# Convert Jquery plugin Into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there anybody here who knows the Javascript-equivalent or the Javascript version of the code below?

```
(function($) {
$.fn.green = function() {
var selector = this;
selector.css('color' , 'green');
};
})(jQuery);
```

And so on I will call this :

```
$('p').green();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `prototype` method, you wan override or set basics JS methods to `Elements`,`Objects`,`type` etc...

Example

```js
Element.prototype.Color = function(color)
{
  this.style.color=color;
}

Element.prototype.Green = function()
{
  this.style.color="green";
}

document.getElementById("myid").Color("red");
document.getElementById("secondid").Green();
```

```html
<div id="myid">Div element</div>
<div id="secondid">Second div</div>
```